# Каким образом лучше всего ограничить доступ к сайту для незалогиненных пользователей

Tags: javascript, java, servlet

Дано: web приложение на чистом java(без фреймворков). Необходимо перенаправлять незарегистрированных пользователей на страницу логина. Как лучше всего это сделать? Есть идеи реализовать с помощью filter или js (sessionStorage) или куки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, самое простое завести filter, который будет проверять наличие признака "авторизованности" пользователя в запросе. Таким признаком может быть например cookie с каким-нибудь токеном, по которому вы однозначно сможете "опознать" пользователя. Либо что угодно, что поможет Вам однозначно определять пользователя.